# Mongoose in function doesn't return anything

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query my database but for some reason I never get results when I know there are 3 things into my database. I've made this function:

```
function toJson()
{

  var test = [];

  async.series({
    rooms : function() { return Room.find(); }
  }
  , function(err, results) {

    test = results.rooms;

  });

  return test;

}
```

How does this come ? I'm guessing it has something to do that mongoose his method (search) is async..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toJson` is returning immediately, but the `return test;` happens immediately. You need to make `toJson` take a callback instead—you don't even need to use `async.series` here:

```js
function toJson(callback) {
    Room.find(function(err, results) {
        callback(results);
    });
}
```

This will kind of do what you want -- but you shouldn't ignore `err` like you're proposing.